# Page doesn't hide the element when click on TabPanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tabpanel

Problem that script doesn't execute when moving between panels. It execute just when pressing F5. 
I have ProductList.aspx file where I have TabPanels such as:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pProductList" runat="server">
                    <asp:TabContainer ID="tabProductList" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" OnActiveTabChanged="tabProductList_ActiveTabChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:TabPanel ID="TabProductListCatalog" runat="server" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Resource, TabProductListCatalog %>">
                        </asp:TabPanel>
                        <asp:TabPanel ID="TabProductListPicture" runat="server" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Resource, TabProductListPicture %>">
                        </asp:TabPanel>
                        <asp:TabPanel ID="TabProductListList" runat="server" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Resource, TabProductListList %>">
                        </asp:TabPanel>
                    </asp:TabContainer>
                </asp:Panel>
```

and the ProductListTable.ascx where is button:

```
<th class="products text-right">
            <asp:Button ID="btIntoBasketAll" runat="server" onclick="btIntoBasketAll_Click" CssClass="btn btn-basic btn-sm" ToolTip="<%$ Resources: Resource, BasketAfterInsertAllTitle %>" Text="<%$ Resources: Resource, BasketAfterInsertTitle %>" visible='true' />                
                </th>
```

script that doesn't work well (placed at the bottom of ProductListTable.ascx ):

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
                if ($('#AddToBasket').is(':visible')) {
                    document.getElementById('<%=btIntoBasketAll.ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'visible';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('<%=btIntoBasketAll.ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
        </script>
```

And Panel "AddToBasket" hiding and showing. This works, but when only pressing F5. Whenever I move between Panels, It looks that this script doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

use: display :none instead of visibility : hidden
and display : block instead of visiblility : visible.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you refresh the page because that is the only time the code is executed.

If you want to run this code every time a TabPanel is clicked you can wrap the code in a function can add that function to the TabPanel's `onclick` attribute.

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    function tabPanelClicked(){
       if ($('#AddToBasket').is(':visible')) {
            document.getElementById('<%=btIntoBasketAll.ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'visible';
       } else {
            document.getElementById('<%=btIntoBasketAll.ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'hidden';
       }
    }
    tabPanelClicked();
</script>
```

ProductList.aspx

```
<asp:TabPanel ID="TabProductListCatalog" runat="server" HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Resource, TabProductListCatalog %>" onclick="tabPanelClicked()">
```

Add the `onclick` attribute to all TabPanels

Comment: No, I want to execute It whenever the TabPanel is selected, this button is in file where TapPanel is referencing - ProductListTable.ascx.

Comment: And where to place the script? ProductList.aspx, or where is button located - ProductListTable.ascx? (TabPanel is in ProductList.aspx)

Comment: @JúliusMarko In `ProductList.ascx`. This script should appear only once in the webpage. If you want to run it when the page finish loading put it at the end of the page and add `tabPanelClicked();` after the function's definition.

Comment: When I add OnClientClick="tabPanelClicked", the TabContainer with TabPanels dissapear. Does the .aspx knows the location of function? (in .ascx file)

Comment: Now the, TabPanel is here. But when I move between panels, When I come to ProductListTable panel, the function seems doing nothing. It should hide the button, but nothing. However, when F5 refresh, function executes. I really don't know where the problem can be.